# How can I replace a string in a file matching another string in a different file with complete line?

Tags: bash, bioinformatics

I am trying to replace all ID's in a file with a single line said file looks like this (I attempted to make a simplified version but clearly failed, so this is the what a real file looks like this one is simple but most of them are several times longer.

Input 1, Single Line, ID's do not repeat themselves and look like this "YP_009200749.1" the first letter and last digit can vary, but are always a letter and a digit following a "." symbol and the word lenght doesnt vary.

Input1.txt

```
(YP_009200749.1:0.3521069763,(((YP_009200752.1:0.1342966877,YP_009201108.1:0.1515144780)100:0.7205735552,YP_009005351.1:0.6591369564)42:0.1057074658,(((YP_002456109.1:0.4799927899,((YP_006986515.1:0.1381934271,YP_008060763.1:0.0883370194)88:0.1406150048,YP_009195060.1:0.0000026798)100:0.7112151583)36:0.0935282669,WP_018865087.1:0.7100853157)48:0.1594074770,WP_144358678.1:0.7738918924)47:0.2378788195)60:0.2963466642,YP_004957544.1:1.1578177957);
```

This is to be replaced with the full line in another file with the matching ID's, said ID's are not in the same order as the initial file. This is the exact file since I can't resume it properly." **The ">" is not a typo** and the "..." just means the file has several ID's in the same format, the text next to the ID's can vary in word lenght from 2 to several.

Input2.txt

```
>YP_009200749.1 hypothetical protein AYO145A_010 [Escherichia phage vB_EcoM_AYO145A]
>YP_009200752.1 hypothetical protein VPFG_00296 [Vibrio phage nt-1]
...
```

I initially wanted it to look like this (with or without the ">") since it's basically the full line.

Output.txt

```
(YP_009200749.1 hypothetical protein AYO145A_010 [Escherichia phage vB_EcoM_AYO145A]:0.3521069763,(((YP_009200752.1 hypothetical protein VPFG_00296 [Vibrio phage nt-1]:0.1342966877,...
```

But the best result would be

```
(Escherichia phage vB_EcoM_AYO145A:0.3521069763,(((Vibrio phage nt-1:0.1342966877,...
```

I'm currently attempting to do this in bash but can't find a way to detect ID's in the first file, code I found on another answers lacks this part as well.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't appear to match your description.  Nowhere in your output do you have `YP_009200752.1`.  Also, are the `.` literal? It would be helpful if you can further clarify your file1, file2 and output

Comment: Sorry, the "..." represent numeric values, and I fixed one of the ID's since it was repeating itself in the desired output. the single "." in the ID is literal, only the "..." is an attempt of abbreviating several numbers which cloud the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In SO, we help smoothly developpers when their questions are unambiguous. Your input and output sample contain `text` but you don't say if this text contains spaces or not. Better a random text `My text blablabla first` and `My text blablabla second` than an abbreviation; same thing about the numbers. Finally, I assume your second file doesn't contain `>` at the beginning of each line. This must be a tipo, I suppose.

Comment: Please post also any coding attempt you have done.

Comment: @Alphonse your attempt to not “cloud the desired output” is actually making it a lot harder to help you.  Here is what you need to do. 1) Clearly mark what file1 is 2) clearly mark what file2 is 3) clearly mark what your desired output is.  4) rather then replace unique strings of digits with the same ... (which makes it completely ambiguous) instead replace the long string with a much shorter string, like `123` or `987`.  Just make sure that the shorter strings of digits are *unique* and show up in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the first file is called `inputline` and the second one `table`. I also assume there is no `>` in front of the lines of that second file.

As far as I guess from your explanation, this could be the solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  (NR == FNR) { t[$1] = $0 }
  (NR > FNR) { for (i in t) { sub(i, t[i]) }; print }
' table inputline
```

If the same ID can occur several times in your first file (which you don't mention), change the function `sub()` by `gsub()`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, the ">" was not a typo but changing the format in the table was trivial and after some reformating the output was perfect, after giving it a tought I was also able to simplify the rest of the table to accomodate an ideal output with this command using the cut function.